# transform a series-type column into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, api

I have a rest api that returns me some data, among them some in the format of links, so I call this link and store it all in a dataframe, but I need to remove some values ​​from these lists and concatenate with the dataframe, anyone know a way to do this?

```
 response = requests.get(url,auth=(usr,psw),headers=headers)
 df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['result']) 
 def get_data_from_link (data):
 return requests.get(data['link'],auth=(usr,psw),headers=headers).json()

 df['assignment_group_response']=df['assignment_group'].apply(get_data_from_link)
```

column I need to transform

```
0      {'result': {'attested_date': '', 'skip_sync': ...
1      {'result': {'attested_date': '', 'skip_sync': ...
2      {'result': {'attested_date': '', 'skip_sync': ...
```

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear. What does "these lists" contain? Is it already part of the dataframe? What is the end output expected to look like?

Comment: exactly, the list is already part of the dataframe column, what I want to do is transform a field that 'name' that exists in it into a column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial dataframe after fetching your data using the link:

```
    assignment_group_response
0   {'name': 'abc', 'extra': {'value': 123}}
1   {'name': 'def', 'extra': {'value': 456}}
2   {'name': 'xyz', 'extra': {'value': 789}}
```

Now, I'll create new columns and get the values from the nested dictionary

```py
df["name"] = df["assignment_group_response"].apply(lambda x: x["name"])
df["extra"] = df["assignment_group_response"].apply(lambda x: x["extra"])
df["value"] = df["assignment_group_response"].apply(lambda x: x["extra"]["value"])
```

After adding the columns, the dataframe would look like:

```
                   assignment_group_response   name         extra   value
0   {'name': 'abc', 'extra': {'value': 123}}    abc {'value': 123}  123
1   {'name': 'def', 'extra': {'value': 456}}    def {'value': 456}  456
2   {'name': 'xyz', 'extra': {'value': 789}}    xyz {'value': 789}  789
```